# Prompt user for email when signup with facebook and removed access to email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, devise, omniauth-facebook

I'm building a rails application and usign devise and omniauth-facebook for facebook authentication.

When the user signup with facebook, facebook prompts user to give access to the fields we requested.

If the user un checked the email field, facebook doesn't return email. But devise needs email field to create a user.
How can I handle this situation?

Comment: In callback action to the oauth request, build the user and check if it is valid. If not, render a user form with most details prefilled (fetched from facebook) and other details shall be filled by user.

Comment: You won’t _get_ an e-mail address for every Facebook user – lots of them might not even have one on file with Facebook, if they signed up using their mobile …

Answer (score 0):

If the user refuse to communicate its email, asking for it anyway will not make him happy...

The best thing to do is to respect that and create a migration to remove the requirement on the email field.

```
change_column :users, :email, :string, null: true
```

do not forget to remote index and foreign_keys too

To Identify your user i sugges tyou associate an `Identity` model to it, that will handle the return fields : `provider_id, provider_name, name, username`, etc.
Thus you can add more social identifications easily.

Answer (score 0):

If you can live without email then @gdurelle will work but considering that will be highly unlikely since email is used for number of purposes in the applications specially for communicating with user, you might want to take one of the following options when user refuses to give permission for email address,

- When user returns to your app, tell them they cannot sign up without and it is mandatory for them in order to use app. With that, also let them know that you have proper privacy and data protection policy and they need not to worry
- In case user still refuses give them an option to sign up without facebook and plain email/password way and later ask for the permissions for facebook when you will already have the email address